# How to configure JPA at run time(specialy schema of tables)

Tags: java, xml, hibernate, jpa

I am using JPA and I use Entity XML mapping Files to config my persistence layer on the other hand I have multiple database schemas in an Oracle database

In the persistence configuration,  i want to have only one EntityManagerFactory and in fact i want to have connection with database with only one schema(USER).

Statically, I can specify schema name one by one to my Entities in Mapping files like this:

```
<entity class="package.MyClass" name="MyClass">
<table name="MYTABLE"  schema="mySchema"/>
```

My persistence provider in this project is: `org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence`

I want to use a placeholder for specifying schema and replace that when JPA scan mapping files to configure itself.

```
<entity class="package.MyClass" name="MyClass">
<table name="MYTABLE"  schema="@placeholder"/>
```

at config time replace `@placeholder` with mySchema

1. Is anyway to do this?
2. Which part (class) in JPA scan XML mapping files and can i customize that class to do this replace for me?

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use the [bootstrap procedure](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/entitymanager/3.6/reference/en/html/configuration.html#setup-configuration-bootstrapping) to access the `EntityManagerFactory` and the `EntityManager` at runtime to override the properties.